# regex.replace problem

Tags: c#, regex

I want do replace 
why this code don't work?

```
MessageBox.Show( Regex.Replace(Regex.Escape(@"c:\www\html"), Regex.Escape(@"c:\www\"), "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn’t work because you escaped not only your search pattern but also your query string. Don’t do that:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
    @"c:\www\html", Regex.Escape(@"c:\www\"), "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```